# Rails: dynamic environmental settings without magic numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables

Short version: Where should I store environment-specific IDs?  ENV['some-variable']? Somewhere else?

Long version:

Let's say I have a model called Books and a book has a Category. (For the sake of this question, let's say a book only has one category.)

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end
```

Now let's say one category is called 'erotica.' And I want to suppress erotica books in my type ahead. That seems straight forward. But in production and in development 'erotica' has a different ID. I don't want my code to be ID dependent. I don't want it to be string dependent (in case 'erotica' is renamed pr0n or whatever).

I think I should have something like

```
def suppress_method
  suppress_category_id = look_up_suppression_id
  ...
end
```

but where should 'look up' look?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Taking this approach will be brittle,  what if you want to suppress multiple categories?  Erotica *and* Politics?  The best design here is for you to actually add 'suppressed' as a boolean to category in a migration, and maintain that in your application's administration interface.  After you've done that you can add a named scope like:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :not_suppressed, :conditions=>{:suppressed=>false}
  # or for rails 3
  scope :not_suppressed, where(:suppressed=>false)
end
```

Then just update your type ahead code to do:

```
Category.not_suppressed.find ...
```

Rather than

```
Category.find
```

Comment: I agree that would cleaner. However, I am really just more interested in where a environment specific value like that should be stored. And what's the best way to store/recover it?

Comment: That's what the config/environments/foo.rb files are for